# mongoose: $match isn't find documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I created a schema `Machine`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import moment from 'moment';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MachineSchema = new Schema({
    device_name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    state: String,
    count_pings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    created_at: {
        type : Number,
        default: moment().format('x')
    },
    last_work_time_at: {
        type : Number,
        default: moment().format('x')
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Machine', MachineSchema);
```

I send the query using aggregate framework to MongoDB:

```
require('dotenv').config();
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Machine from './models/machine';

const fiveMinutesAgo = moment().subtract(process.env.INTERVAL_TIME_IN_MINUTES, 'minutes').format('x');

Machine.aggregate([
        {$match: {last_work_time_at: {$lt: fiveMinutesAgo}}},
        {$project: {_id: 1, device_name: 1, last_work_time_at: 1}}
    ])
      .then(results => {
            console.log(results);
      })
```

I want to get all documents for which value of `last_work_time_at` is less than value of `fiveMinutesAgo`.

I use mongoose of version 4.11.7.

Here, for example the document stored in collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6c8a5811e812935f3c6d4"),
    "device_name" : "cg0011",
    "state" : "unworking",
    "last_work_time_at" : 1504102558069.0,
    "created_at" : 1504102558069.0,
    "count_pings" : 15844,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have same else 10 documents and for which absolutely every value of field `last_work_time_at` is less than value of `fiveMinutesAgo, but result of query is empty array.

I don't understand why don't get any documents by query. I'm thinking that somewhere made a little error and that is why isn't search it still.
Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `moment().subtract(process.env.INTERVAL_TIME_IN_MINUTES, 'minutes').toDate()`. Mongoose "autocasting" does not work in aggregation pipelines. You need to convert to a JavaScript `Date` object. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1599

Comment: Actually `moment().subtract(process.env.INTERVAL_TIME_IN_MINUTES, 'minutes').valueOf()` since you actually store numeric as milliseconds. Same reasoning. The aggregation framework does not access the schema for "autocasting" as methods like `.find()` can do. This is simply because documents in an aggregation pipeline can change to a shape that no longer matches the schema. It is arguable that this is not true for the first stage of a pipeline, however that is not how it is implemented.

Comment: Good answer. Earlier I made also same the query without `moment` or similar libraries and query executed to MongoDB, but later I will have add `moment` in my app and then got a empty result after executing query to MongoDB. Many thanks, that you remind to me about it and explained very fine why.